# Cohen's Kappa analysis, probems with data input

Tags: r

I need to measure inter observer reliability of two peoples ID's of 25 monkeys.
 packages downloaded are: `irr` and `psych`

Effectively my two columns look like the ones below:

```
obs_1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
obs_1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

so the 2 in the obs 1 column indicates a disagreement between me and the other observer of a mmonkeys name (ID).

I combined the above columns into a data frame:

```
df2<- as.data.frame (cbind(obs_1,obs_2))
```

however when i try to run a kappa cohens analysis using either of the following:

```
cohen.kappa(df2)
```

or

```
cohen.kappa(scores,w=NULL,n.obs=2,alpha=.05,levels=NULL)
```

I do net recieve an estimate for k and my output looks like below:

```
Cohen Kappa and Weighted Kappa correlation coefficients and confidence boundaries 
                 lower estimate   upper
unweighted kappa -4.4e-07        0 4.4e-07
weighted kappa   -4.4e-07        0 4.4e-07

Number of subjects = 25
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: you should never need to do `as.data.frame(cbind(...))`, just do `data.frame(...)`.

Comment: I'm not personally familiar with Cohen's Kappa, but is `k` just `kappa`? The [package pdf doc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/psych.pdf) references 'k' only in a comparison to ICC with regards to weighting, which if I understand correctly is an input, not an output. (I'm probably off a little, just asking.)

Comment: It might be that this question is better suited for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). I'm not voting to migrate at this point, but think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your data has nearly no variation. The only variation is a disagreement. Hence, you get a Kappa of zero. E.g. you will get a Kappa of 1 if you change your example to complete agreement:

```
obs_1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
obs_2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

df2<- data.frame(obs_1,obs_2)

cohen.kappa(df2)

Cohen Kappa and Weighted Kappa correlation coefficients and confidence boundaries 
                 lower estimate upper
unweighted kappa     1        1     1
weighted kappa       1        1     1
```

Comment: Thank you, is there any way you can think of of doing this analysis with the sort of agreement i have? i.e obviously there are a lot of monkey names, I have just used the numbers to indicate whether me and the other observer agreed or not. Would there be a better way of demonstrating this agreement/disagreement for this type of analysis or would another analysis be better?

Comment: If you work with the actual monkey names or monkey IDs, you should get reasonable estimates of Kappa. What you are currently doing is calculating an agreement/disagreement indicator and then run the Kappa function. Just skip the first step.